# Making multiple copies of a cell and duplicating it for a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of different names that I would like to duplicate each one by 3 copies of itself. For instance:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

to the following:

```
A
A
A
B
B
B
C
C
C
D
D
D
E
E
E
```

How I would I accomplish this in excel? Can it be done in Excel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are SOOO many ways to do this... One way would be using something along the lines of the `OFFSET()` function like so:

Supposing your original list was in cells `A1:A5`, say. You could then put this formula where you want it:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,ROUNDDOWN((ROW(A1)-1)/5,0),0)
```

and drag it down for the 25 rows you want.

In essence, what you're saying is:

Offset cell `A1` by `ROUNDDOWN((ROW(A1)-1)/5,0)` rows and `0` columns.

Looking at that `ROUNDDOWN()` function:

```
Row(A1) = 1   (Similarly, Row(A2) = 2, etc...
(Row(A1)-1) / 5 = 0/5 ; 1/5 ; 2/5 ; .....
Rounddowwn(...) means 0/5 to 4/5 becomes 0 ; 5/5 to 9/5 becomes 1 ; etc
```

Therefore, it will offset `A1` by `0` rows and `0` columns 5 times then by `1` row and `0` columns for the next 5, etc.

Hope that makes sense :)

---

**EDIT:**

The original question asked for 3 copies of each value, not 5 - I'm leaving the answer as-is purposefully with this edit so someone else can see how to change it to any number of repetitions as wanted... All that would change would be:

```
 =OFFSET($A$1,ROUNDDOWN((ROW(A1)-1)/3,0),0)
```

Simply, divide by `3` rather than `5` for that to occur...

Comment: Did you ever know that you're my hero?

Comment: :) - Yes... Yes, I did :p  More seriously, though, welcome to Stack overflow and hope it helps you as much as its helped so many of us!!

Comment: This is a very clever solution. Looks like the asker is satisfied, but I believe they wanted 3 copies of each, so replace the 5 with a 3.

Comment: Sorry, @MattCremeens - You are completely right... Just mis-read it.. Thanks for that!!

Comment: @JohnBustos Don't be sorry. This is a fine display of thinking outside the box. The error was a technicality. :)